# Unrecognized font family 'anticon'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dependencies

I've been coding along with a YouTube tutorial and have been running into this error message. I have the proper import statement and the proper dependency installed so I'm not sure what the issue is.

**Error message in iOS simulator:**
[image]

**The Component I'm calling Anticon in:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {windowHeight, windowWidth} from '../utils/Dimensions';

import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const FormInput = ({labelValue, placeholderText, iconType, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <View style={styles.iconStyle}>
        <AntDesign name={iconType} size={25} color="#666" />
      </View>
      <TextInput
        value={labelValue}
        style={styles.input}
        numberOfLines={1}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        placeholderTextColor="#666"
        {...rest}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FormInput;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: '100%',
    height: windowHeight / 15,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  iconStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRightColor: '#ccc',
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    width: 50,
  },
  input: {
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
    color: '#333',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputField: {
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: windowWidth / 1.5,
    height: windowHeight / 15,
    fontSize: 16,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

**The screen I'm attempting to use anticon in:**

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import FormInput from '../components/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../components/FormButton';
import SocialButton from '../components/SocialButton';
import {AuthContext} from '../navigation/AuthProvider';

import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const {login} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('../assets/rn-social-logo.png')}
        style={styles.logo}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>RN Social App</Text>

      <FormInput
        labelValue={email}
        onChangeText={userEmail => setEmail(userEmail)}
        placeholderText="Email"
        iconType="user"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
      />

      <FormInput
        labelValue={password}
        onChangeText={userPassword => setPassword(userPassword)}
        placeholderText="Password"
        iconType="lock"
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />

      <FormButton
        buttonTitle="Sign In"
        onPress={() => login(email, password)}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.forgotButton} onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View>
        <SocialButton
          buttonTitle="Sign In with Facebook"
          btnType="facebook"
          color="#4867aa"
          backgroundColor="#e6eaf4"
          onPress={() => {}}
        />

        <SocialButton
          buttonTitle="Sign In with Google"
          btnType="google"
          color="#de4d41"
          backgroundColor="#f5e7ea"
          onPress={() => {}}
        />
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.forgotButton}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
        <Text style={styles.navButtonText}>
          Don't have an acount? Create here
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  logo: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 28,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: '#051d5f',
  },
  navButton: {
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  forgotButton: {
    marginVertical: 35,
  },
  navButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#2e64e5',
  },
});
```

**My dependencies with anticon:**

```
{
  "name": "socialapp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "npm:@react-native-community/async-storage",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-async-storage": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this in your info.plist file in the ios directory and don't forget to pod install:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you!

Comment: nothing has changed. still ```unrecognized font family 'noname.ttf'```

Comment: Legendary, thank you. Is this on the docs somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's on the github library page.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, hope this helps someone...

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
Icon.loadFont().then();
...
<Icon name={iconName} color={color} size={size} />;
```

Comment: This is super odd, why does this work? There's a warning error saying "Font failed to load" but all the icons are there. Will this only works on simulator but completely failed on device?

Answer (score 3):

Complete steps working for me in react-native version 0.70.4

1. Install react-native-vector-icons using this

npm install --save react-native-vector-icons

2. Reveal project in finder and go to below path :
   ProjectName-> node_modules -> react-native-vector-icons -> Fonts
3. Add all font names from Fonts folder in Info.plist file with key UIAppFonts like this : (Attached screen shot)
   [image]
4. Open Project-> iOS-> Project.xcworkspace file into Xcode and follow below steps : (Attached screen shot)

- Open project properties by selecting project in Xcode.
- Under Build Phrases, expand Copy Bundle Resources and add fonts from node_module folder.
  [image]

5. create a react-native.config.js file at the root of project and add below code :

```js
module.exports = {
      dependencies: {
        'react-native-vector-icons': {
          platforms: {
            ios: null,
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

6. Using vector icon :

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
Icon.loadFont();

const VectorIconApp = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Icon name="checkcircle" size={30} color="#4F8EF7" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default VectorIconApp;
```

);
};

export default VectorIconApp;

7. Clean, Build and Run application and it will display vector-icon.

Comment: your answer is very helpful for me,
I think this error is because the version issue of react native, after 0.70.0 some configuration change for some packages,
Before your answer I followed lots of articles and videos but icon not configure in iOS

Answer (score 0):

1. Add ttf file into ios by clicking on project name => add file (fontname.ttf)
2. Add fontname.ttf in info.plist where all vector icons present

Answer (score 0):

**XCode**-> When you drag the "**Fonts**" folder from the **rect-native-vector-icons** folder to your project, make sure your app is checked under "**Add to targets**" and that "**Create groups**" is checked if you add the whole folder "**Fonts**". This will work for you!